# How can I leave a level after donning the Boots of Introspection?

Tags: candy-box-2

In Candy Box 2, is there any way I can leave a level if I'm wearing the Boots of Introspection? It's great to wear the Merchant's Hat and gain lots of candies, but you could gain even more if you wear the Boots of Introspection and somehow leave. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Boots of Introspection on, you only don't move forward when you are on the ground. So, you can leave the level by jumping until you reach the end.

Comment: Wow. I just made a million candies in two minutes at the castle walls. Thanks!